# Rasbian on a banana pi

Tags: raspbian

I'd like to run Rasbian (not bananian) on my Banana Pi M1, but the image I found for that is Wheezy (http://www.lemaker.org/product-bananapi-download-23.html) so the first thing I need to do is update to at least Stretch (preferably Buster).

However, after updating my sources.lst and rasbpi.lst files to jesse per [this page](https://pimylifeup.com/upgrade-raspbian-wheezy-to-raspbian-jessie/), when I tried to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and none of them take any effect because the first one failed (hey, no surprise, you have to get your sources updated before you can install anything):

```
Err http://repository.wolfram.com stable Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'repository.wolfram.com'
Err http://raspberrypi.collabora.com wheezy Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'raspberrypi.collabora.com'
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jesse Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jesse Release
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse Release
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jesse/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]
Err http://archive.raspberrypi.org jesse/ui armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jesse/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jesse/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jesse/ui Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspberrypi.org jesse/ui Translation-en
Err http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Err http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/contrib armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Err http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/non-free armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Err http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/rpi armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/contrib Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/rpi Translation-en_GB
Ign http://archive.raspbian.org jesse/rpi Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://raspberrypi.collabora.com/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'raspberrypi.collabora.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://repository.wolfram.com/raspbian/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'repository.wolfram.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jesse/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/jesse/ui/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.133 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jesse/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jesse/contrib/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jesse/non-free/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jesse/rpi/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.191 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[Someone posted the same problem](https://lb.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=190850), but they posted on someone else's thread so maybe that is why they didn't get a solution. I, too, checked my connectivity with `ping mirrordirector.raspbian.org` and `ping archive.raspberrypi.org` and got 0% packet loss, so the issue is not connectivity to those servers, at least.

Comment: This smells strongly of [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) in that you presumably have *some concrete reason* for wanting to install Raspbian that likely has a better solution than using a distro tailored to a different device.

Comment: IKR? 
At this point though, @goldilocks , I'm trying to find **any** OS that will run on my pi and allow me to use Bluetooth, Plex server, and Alexa. That is enough of a challenge.

Comment: That's what I'm observing:  Your real question is what to replace Bananian with, not how to install Raspbian on a Banana Pi.   Of course, you can't ask that here, but you *could* ask on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  Keep in mind that Raspbian was not something that was released by the Pi manufacturers to go with their device -- it was created by people in the linux community who got their hands on that device...

Comment: ...That community is still around, lol, as is the distribution Raspbian was/is based upon, Debian armel, one of three ARM variants they officially support: https://www.debian.org/ports/arm/ .  All models of banana are compatible with at least the armhf variant, and at that point, *most* of the distro umbrellas (Ubuntu, Fedora, Arch, etc) have those.  So you are not stuck with Raspbian or nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious error is the use of `jesse` rather than the correct `jessie`.

I doubt you can use Wolfram as I doubt it's licence permits its use on a Banana Pi.

Have you checked Raspbian's licence to see if that permits use on a Banana Pi?

Comment: Supposing Raspbian is illegal on other hardware (which I doubt if it is GNU)... What would **you** recommend I run on my Banana? Bananian is no longer supported!

Comment: You're right -- there is no chance the Foundation (or whoever is directly/indirectly involved) can restrict the use of Raspbian in a way that contradicts the GPL.  There can be restrictions on the use of some of the bundled software, though, such as Wolfram and GPU firmware (but the latter wouldn't be used anyway).  *"What would you recommend I run on my Banana? "* -> Use a generic ARM distro, I'd guess all those chips are supported in the vanilla kernel (if not, using Raspbian won't help).   You likely have to structure the card image yourself, but that is pretty trivial.

Comment: @NH Not all of Raspbian is GNU. Why do you think one of the repositories is called `non-free`?

Answer (score 6):

Banana Pi is supported by [Armbian](https://www.armbian.com/bananapi/), Ubuntu and Debian, both based on a mainline kernel. This is what you should be using.

I'm pretty sure an update touching the kernel, drivers and the firmware (such as one from Wheezy to Buster) will ruin any compatibility tricks that allowed to run Raspbian on a Banana Pi in the first place.